# Listing Shopify Products Via API From Multiple Collections

Tags: shopify

I know how to list products from a specific custom collection using APi

```
...products.json?collection_id=xxxx
```

How do I get to list products from two or three specific collections? If there a way of telling API to list products that are found only in these collections, i. e. collection A and collection B only?

Comment: Have you read the Shopify API documentation?

Comment: @Quality : yes I did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is accomplished through the Collect API. Products are not directly associated with Custom Collections- they are associated with Collects, which are then associated with Custom Collections. So, with the Collect API, you obtain all Collects that are associated with a Custom Collection, and then retrieve all products associated with those Collects. You can even obtain these products in a single request (shown below; see gotchas).

See here in the documentation:

[Getting all Collects for a certain Custom Collection](https://help.shopify.com/api/reference/collect#index)

[Getting a list of specific products](https://help.shopify.com/api/reference/product#index)

---

### Example:

(Since we're only concerned about obtaining the product IDs from the collects, we can pass `product_id` to the `fields` parameter for faster response times)

`GET /admin/collects.json?collection_id=841564295&fields=product_id`

Response:

```
{
  "collects": [
    {
      "product_id": 921728736,
    },
    {
      "product_id": 632910392,
    }
  ]
}
```

`GET /admin/products.json?ids=921728736,632910392`

Response:

```
{
    "products": [ ... ]
}
```

---

### Gotchas:

There is a default limit of 50 items per respone for both the Collect and Product endpoints, so you will need to handle pagination. You can up this 50 limit to 250 with `limit=250` which will reduce your overall number of requests.

While there is no limit to how many IDs you specify with the `ids` parameter, the Product endpoint will still respect this default or specified `limit`. So, it's best to group your IDs into groups of 250, pass them separated by commas as the value for `ids`, then remember to add the `limit=250` parameter to avoid having to paginate.